# Difference between a[0,0] and a[0][0] in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array 'a', a[0,0] and a[0][0] return the same result, so how do I choose them and what is the difference between them?

Comment: Please show the same result and give them unique values to not be confused.

Comment: One is two indexing operations, the other one.  For simple cases like this the result is the same.  But sooner or later you need need to read more in depth documentation about array indexing.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a` is 2D, `a[0]` will return the first row. You can then index into that by column, which is what you're doing with `a[0][0]`. Both options return the upper left element. The single indexer call (aka, `[0,0]`) is likely more performant, if that's all you're doing, but it can be convenient to iterate through the rows and work with them individually.